# mysqlhotcopy not working. Why?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to backup a database using mysqlhotcopy. All the files are local. I'm using xampp with php5.4 and mysql5.5.

When I put the following line in the SQL command line I get an error:

```
sql: mysqlhotcopy -u root -p password database /tmp/ 
error: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: str_replace("asdasd asdasd asdasdas dasdasd asdasd", "PLEASE DELETE MY POST", $post);

Comment: @nutman: you can delete your own post; don't vandalize it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run that from the command line, not in phpAdmin.

Comment: sorry, I am obviously a complete noob! 
I did try doing it via the command line (mysql.exe) but it gives me the same error.
I was under the impression that the SQL box in phpMyAdmin just ran the code through the command line anyway?